# finding the minimum of two cells in different rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data frame with columns `A` and `B`. Column `C` shall be the minimum value of A.shift(1), the preceding row, and B, the current row:

```
         A     B     C
Index
  1    100   200    NaN
  2    150   230    100
  3    130   110    110
```

Is there a simple way to do it? How can the min() function be constructed with cells that do not belong to the same row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `numpy.minimum()` to find out the minimum element of two Series in sequence:

```
import numpy as np
df['C'] = np.minimum(df.A.shift(), df.B)

df
#           A     B     C
# Index         
#     1   100   200   NaN
#     2   150   230 100.0
#     3   130   110 110.0
```